# Is it OK to change a question's intent after it's clearly leading to a dead end?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

After I asked my question, the comments resulted in answers like, "you can't really do that". Is it better to start a new question or to rephrase the original like, how would you work around X, rather than can you do X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, in response to comments, you edit your question so it becomes a better question; you are doing it right.

Comments are exactly for that. As the tool-tip says: *"Use comments to ask for clarification and add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments"*. So you shouldn't be afraid of changing your question in response to comments.

If your edits invalidate some of these comments, you are even encouraged to flag those as *"no longer needed"*.

A comment asking you to provide further details (e.g. the specific error you received, what version are you working with, etc) is not very useful if those details have been already edited into the question. Better to get rid of it, unless some other useful information in the comment would be lost as well.

Comments should be treated as ephemeral. Q&A are the site's meat and potatoes.

Of course, if someone **often** finds themselves **drastically** changing their questions in response to comments, it could mean than more time should be spent thinking about the question *before* posting it.

Finally, if a question has been answered, it's not fair to edit the meaning of the question in a way that invalidates existing answers, and it shouldn't be done. That kind of edit will be rolled back.

Comment: The only conundrum I can think of about this last part is: a question is asked, answered, and then closed as too broad/unclear/etc. Should you edit it to make it on-topic, even if it invalidates an existing answer?

Comment: _Mumbles something about answering off-topic questions..._

Comment: @André Yup, I know. It's a sorry state of things. But those do exist. Pretty sure there are a few posts dealing with this anyway.

Comment: One issue with your blanket statement of "if a question has been answered".  I would say that if the answer was a guess to an unclear question, then you shouldn't worry about invalidating that answer.  The answerer should have clarified before guessing.  But if the original question was clear and the question changes as a result of the answer and/or comments, then a new question is warrented

Comment: I mostly agree @psubsee2003. Read my first comment under this answer. :)

Comment: @yivi I don't even think it needs to be closed.  If someone answers a bad (broad/unclear) question because they think they can, and the question can be fixed, it should be fixed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 fully agree. We do what makes sense from case to case and if it makes sense to edit a question, you just do it. If that makes a bad answer even worse, you click on the downvote button twice as hard.